# Power impact of setInterval() in Location Request with GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-googleapiclient

I am trying to understand what is the battery savings we get by increasing setInterval() duration when constructing Location Request. I tried two scenarios

1. Location Request with setInterval() with 60000millis
2. Location Request with setInterval() as 500millis

In both the cases there is a GPS icon in status bar when location updates are started. But accuracy returned by request2 is better than request1. Please explain what is happening internally and what is the battery impact due to this

Location Request looks like this for scenario 1

```
private final LocationRequest mLocationRequestHighAccuracy = LocationRequest
        .create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(60000)
        .setFastestInterval(100);
```

Comment: I think one location request drain battery. If u request more, more will drain. And also one impact of this is the accuracy, one opinion is `.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)` also has impact.

Comment: bjiang: At any time there is only one scenario running.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?